# React Native WebView offline-first or local content

Tags: ios, react-native, offline-caching, visual-studio-app-center, code-push

I am building React Native application with integrated [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/) SDKs (analytics, crash reporting, **CodePush** for in-app updates). This application is only a 'wrapper' for our online web presentation. The requirement is to make it **offline-first** with possibility to update the wrapper or web presentation.

My idea was to attach web presentation files to React Native project and WebView with local HTML source. **BUT** - it works only in emulator. React Native packager (or bundler) is possible to render full HTML file with all it's internal dependencies (JS, fonts, CSS, other assets). Like this:

```
import htmlSource from './presentation/index.html'

<WebView
    source={htmlSource}
    style={styles.webview}
/>
```

This works fine on emulator, but when I create a production build, JS bundle does not contain any HTML dependencies so presentation is only raw HTML without styles and any other assets. So I am not able to render full presentation with WebView. Creating CodePush release (for in-app update) is the same - without assets.

**Do you have any ideas how to make this working?** I need to be able to render presentation when device is offline but when is connected, be able to update it.

We do not want to make a full deploy process to App Store, because of its long review/verify process.

Why it works on emulator but in production build it does not work? Is it possible to make a bundle different way to attach all HTMl file dependencies? Or is it possible to offline-cache the WebView content if I point to URL address?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score -1):

react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output release_ios/index.ios.jsbundle --assets-dest release_ios/

then drag your local css、assets... to assets

[image]